# How to turn this Password validation right?

Tags: javascript

```
var password=123;
var input;
var opp=0;

for(var t=0;t<=2;t++){
  if(password!=input && t<=2){
    input=prompt("enter your password");
  }
  else{
    opp++;
  }
}
if(opp!=0){
  alert("success");
}
else if(opp<1){
  alert("fail");
}
```

im expect it to be a password validation which can only try three times.
but it will failed even with typing correct password in the third try.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what it is you are trying to do, this is totally unsafe.

To easily crack your password challenge, click 'view source' on the browser, and lookup the password.

Please use better authentication, preferably on the server, not in javascript.

Of course you can use Javascript, but not for actual password checking.

---

Since OP is just trying and will never use this in a production environment, here is a working piece of script:

```
var password= "123";
var input;
var tries=1;
var maxTries = 5;
var passed = false;

while ( (!passed) && (tries <= maxTries) ){
    input=prompt("enter your password (attempt nr "+tries+")");
    if (input === password){
        passed = true; // Yeah!
    } else {
        tries = tries + 1;
    }
}

if (passed){
    alert("success");
} else {
  alert("fail");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Let's begin saying this should just be a didactic excercise.***

I suggest you to drop the for loop strategy and embed the logic inside a while loop that will keep running as long as the `attempt` counter variable will be `<=3`.

Until the typed password still doesn't match the expected one, it will keep asking for a new password after saying `fail` for a total amount of 3 attemps max.

If the typed password matched, it just alerts the user saying `success` and exiting the loop.

***Of course as just said by other users, this approach is very wrong in terms of security starting from the fact that the expected password is stored in plain text.***

As a side note, the expected password defined as a literal should be a string literal and not a number.

```js
let password = '123';
let attempt = 0;
let input;

let wasSuccess = false;

while(++attempt<=3){
  input = prompt("enter your password");
  if(input == password){
    wasSuccess = true;
    alert('success');
    break;
  }else{
    alert('fail');
  }
}

if(wasSuccess){
  //perform any logic expected to run after successfully logged in
}
```

Comment: Wow,thanks a lot,I will try again in while loops